# Max And Sum mysql

Tags: mysql, sum, max

I've to get all the orders from one customer, then get the sum of the orders and then get the max order.
I can't use order by and limit.
I got the result but i can't get the make sum and max work properly

here is my current query:

```
SELECT SUM(Qty * UnitPrice) AS Total FROM `Details`
WHERE ONo IN (
    SELECT Orders.Ono
    FROM Orders, Customers
    WHERE Customers.FName = 'Charles' AND Customers.LName = 'Xavier' AND Customers.CNo = Orders.CNo
    GROUP BY Orders.ONo
)
GROUP BY ONo

Total
7.50
20.99
54.47
49.98
8.00
```

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm supposed to get one result left from the sample table I quoted (54.47)

Comment: `ORDER BY SUM(Qty * UnitPrice) DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Not allow to use limit sadly

Comment: @Eray I get the following error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @Eray I removed 'AS T' From your last answer and I got my result. With, Mysql was returning an error. 
Thank you very much

Comment: I am glad to help Robin.. I appreciate if you select my answer below as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT MAX(Total) as MaxTotal FROM (<your query comes here>) AS T
```